# Eigen constructing SimplicialLLT call MatrixL reports error

Tags: eigen

```
    //standard LLT with cholesky
    Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>, Eigen::Lower, Eigen::NaturalOrdering<int>> cholesky;
    cholesky.compute(array0);
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> L = cholesky.matrixL();
```

I'm computing fill-in while when I use `cholesky.matrixL();`
it reports

```
test1: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h:396: Eigen::SparseMatrix<_Scalar, _Flags, _StorageIndex>::Scalar& Eigen::SparseMatrix<_Scalar, _Flags, _StorageIndex>::insertBackByOuterInner(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with _Scalar = float; int _Options = 0; _StorageIndex = int; Eigen::SparseMatrix<_Scalar, _Flags, _StorageIndex>::Scalar = float; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `(m_outerIndex[outer+1]-m_outerIndex[outer]==0 || m_data.index(m_data.size()-1)<inner) && "Invalid ordered insertion (invalid inner index)"' failed.
Aborted
```

What should I do to solve this?
Please!

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. Also, did you check whether `cholesky.info() == Eigen::Success`?